# Is it possible to get logging in netsh interface portproxy

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, logging, port-forwarding, netsh

I am using `netsh interface portproxy` to do some port forwarding on a server. Is there any way at all to see any logs of what was the input sent to the port, whether something was forwarded etc? i.e. does netsh write any logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By itself netsh portproxy only forwards packets from source to destination. You should look towards [Windows firewall  logging](http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/jj717291.aspx) or use some network protocol analyzer like Wireshark.